# Wordpress add_filter after post

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to add custom plugin after single post content. I have tried with `add_filter` and `add_action` to get my plugin printed out.

```
     if(!defined('ABSPATH')) exit;

 function customPlug_plugin_install()
 {

 }

 register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'customPlug_plugin_install');

 function customPlug_plugin_scripts()
 {
    wp_register_script('customPlug_script', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__), 'js/customplug.js', '1.0', true);
    wp_register_script('customPlug_bootstrap_script', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__), 'js/customplug.js', '1.0', true);
    wp_register_script('customPlug_script', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__), 'js/customplug.js', '1.0', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('customPlug_script');
 }


 function my_plugin($content) {
    $content = "Custom Plugin Content";
    return $content;
 }
 add_action('the_content', 'my_plugin');
```

However, this is just returning either the plugin content, or the_content if I comment out `add_filter` or `add_action`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're overwriting current content. You should concatenate your content to current content with `.`

```
function my_plugin($content) 
{
    $content. = "Custom Plugin Content";
    return $content;
}
```